# C++20 ranges sort and filter combined?

Tags: c++, sorting, filter, range

For my terminal emulator I'm trying to implement the DOS *dir* command. As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir), it supports the /a option (apply filters) and the /o option (sort). Each one can be used with multiple attributes. For example */ad* should display directories only, */a-s* should display every file and directory except for system files. These are the attributes in my virtual file system:

```
namespace file_attributes
{
    // DOS/Windows file/directory attributes
    const std::size_t ARCHIVE    = 0UL;
    const std::size_t HIDDEN     = 1UL;
    const std::size_t SYSTEM     = 2UL;
    const std::size_t READ_ONLY  = 3UL;
    const std::size_t COMPRESSED = 4UL;
    const std::size_t ENCRYPTED  = 5UL;
    const std::size_t DIRECTORY  = 6UL;
}

using t_attributes  = std::bitset<24>;
```

By default, DOS should not display hidden and system files, so I create a default filter

```
t_attributes filterAttribs;
filterAttribs.set(file_attributes::HIDDEN, true);
filterAttribs.set(file_attributes::SYSTEM, true);
```

My file nodes are stored in a map. In order to be able to sort them, I need to create a vector of pointers

```
// Get map values and convert them to pointers
auto valuesRangePointers = std::views::values(nodeMap) |
                           std::views::transform([](FileSystemNode& node) { return &node; });

// Copy these pointers into a vector
std::vector<FileSystemNode*> nodes{ valuesRangePointers.begin(), valuesRangePointers.end() };
```

I don't know exactly how can I apply the filters. Sometimes the code works fine on some virtual folders, sometimes it doesn't apply the filters correctly

```
auto filtered = nodes | std::views::filter([&](FileSystemNode* node)
{
    const auto& nodeAttr = node->getAttributes();
    return ((nodeAttr & filterAttribs).to_ulong() == 0UL);
}
```

Is this the correct way to apply a bitmask? The files that have no attributes are almost never shown. And my other question is: how can I combine this filtered output with the sort from the /O command?

```
std::ranges::sort(filtered, sortByDirectoryAscendant); // doesn't compile
std::ranges::sort(nodes, sortByDirectoryAscendant); // does compile and work
```

Also, if I type */og-d*, the system should combine the sort by directory (asc) and sort by date (desc), how can I combine them? (each sorting function is implemented as a lambda)

```
auto sortByDirectoryAscendant = [](FileSystemNode* lhs, FileSystemNode* rhs)
{
    return (lhs->hasAttrib(file_attributes::DIRECTORY) && !rhs->hasAttrib(file_attributes::DIRECTORY));
};

auto sortByDateAscendant = [](FileSystemNode* lhs, FileSystemNode* rhs)
{
    const auto& ld = lhs->getModifyDate();
    const auto& rd = rhs->getModifyDate();

    return (std::tie(ld.year, ld.month, ld.day) < std::tie(rd.year, rd.month, rd.day));
};
```

Comment: I feel like this question is asking two question at once: "Is this way of filtering by file attributes correct?" and also "Why can't I use std::sort in combination with std::views::filter?". I could answer the latter question, and it would be a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should filter the list, convert it to a vector and then sort it. You cannot sort the *view* returned from `views::filter()` because that is not a random access range. `std::ranges::sort` (just like `std::sort`) requires a random access range as its input.

Like this the code should compile fine

```
// Get map values, filter and convert to pointers
auto filtered = 
    std::views::values(nodeMap) |
    std::views::filter([&](FileSystemNode const& node) {
        const auto& nodeAttr = node.getAttributes();
        return ((nodeAttr & filterAttribs).to_ulong() == 0UL);
    }) |
    std::views::transform([](FileSystemNode& node) { return &node; });

// Copy the pointers into a vector
std::vector<FileSystemNode*> nodes{ filtered.begin(), filtered.end() };

// And sort
std::ranges::sort(nodes, sortByDirectoryAscendant);
```